# PHP Planning board table

Tags: php, foreach

I want to make an planning board in PHP, I want it to look like this (tables):

Name1     X
 
Name2
Name3
Name4                                        X
            Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday

I have 2 foreaches, 1 for the names and 1 for the data.

```
foreach($names) {
    foreach($data) {
        <tr>
        <td> $names </td>
        <td> if data['data'] == 1 { X }</td>
        <td> if data['data'] == 2 { X }</td>
        <td> if data['data'] == 3 { X }</td>
         </tr>
    }
}
```

But this code duplicates the names. When I put the tr and the td $names in the other foreach it creates more fields than 4. How can I combine these foreaches?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Where does your $names array come from? How are you defining it? Or is it coming from a database query?

Comment: $names is an array with names from the database

Comment: Can we see some example data for $names and $data? Also, you're outputting all $names

Comment: Basic working of **foreach**: foreach($array as $key => $value), and you are dumping the full array

Comment: Can you show what the arrays contain?

Comment: $names = array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3");
$data = array(array("id" => 1, "data" => 0), array("id" => 2, "data" => 1))

if data must be if data['data']

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your arrays contain, but for starters, you're outputting all the names values, should be something like this.

Now that we have the arrays

```
$data = array(array("id" => 1, "data" => 0), array("id" => 2, "data" => 1))
```

Your code wants to be something like..

```
<?php
    foreach($names as $key => $value) {
        $d = $data[$key]['data']; ?>
        <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $value; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php if ($d == 1) { echo 'X'; } ?></td>
        <td> <?php if ($d == 2) { echo 'X'; } ?></td>
        <td> <?php if ($d == 3) { echo 'X'; } ?></td>
        </tr><?php
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this instance you'll need the 2 foreach loops, nested recursion isn't a bad thing unless you've nested things several levels deep and it's hard to debug.

What you probably need is something like this:

```
//each row is a name
foreach($names as $name){
    echo "<tr>";//<-- new row
    $x = 1;//counter
    //each data is a column
    foreach($data as $d){
        echo "<td>";//<-- new column
        if($d == $x){// is $d equal to 1,2,3,4,[n]
            echo "X";
        }
        echo "</td>";
        $x++;//increment counter
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```